# In Oracle i have quarter names & start period and end period how can convert all those quarters into year?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the data like below.

```
          QUATER NAME   Start Period   end Period
Q-FISCAL   FY20 Q3     1/26/2020      4/25/2020
Q-FISCAL   FY20 Q2     10/27/2019     1/25/2020
Q-FISCAL   FY20 Q1     7/28/2019      10/26/2019
```

I am looking data to be LIKE

```
       FY2020
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull the `FY20` out of the name and then change 20 to 2020; or do something based on the dates? Where is the financial year and quarter cutoffs defined - only here, or somewhere else? (Those seem like unusual cut-offs, but maybe it's just a standard I haven't come across...). Do you have data from other years, and if so what do you want to see - the year against each row, distinct years, most recent...? Please clarify by editing your question, and look at your [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Sample data you have isn't very clear; what exactly makes the `quarter_name`? I presumed that it is *everything* at the beginning of the row, up to the first date. If that's so, see if something like this helps. Even if not right away, this is the principle you might adjust. I'd suggest you do it step-by-step, just like I did, trying to split every part to its own line for better readability.

```
SQL> with test (quarter_name, start_period, end_period) as
  2    (select 'Q-FISCAL FY20 Q3', date '2020-01-26', date '2020-04-25' from dual union all
  3     select 'Q-FISCAL FY20 Q2', date '2019-10-27', date '2020-01-25' from dual union all
  4     select 'Q-FISCAL FY20 Q1', date '2019-07-28', date '2019-10-26' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'Q-FISCAL FY18 Q3', date '2018-01-26', date '2018-04-26' from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    regexp_replace(quarter_name,
 10                   substr(quarter_name, instr(quarter_name, ' ') + 1, 4),
 11                   --
 12                   substr(quarter_name, instr(quarter_name, ' ') + 1, 2)
 13                   ||
 14                   to_char(
 15                           to_date (
 16                                    substr(quarter_name, instr(quarter_name, ' ') + 3, 2),
 17                                    'rrrr'
 18                                   ),
 19                                    'rrrr'
 20                          )
 21                  ) new_quarter_name,
 22    --
 23    start_period,
 24    end_period
 25  from test;

NEW_QUARTER_NAME     START_PERI END_PERIOD
-------------------- ---------- ----------
Q-FISCAL FY2020 Q3   01/26/2020 04/25/2020
Q-FISCAL FY2020 Q2   10/27/2019 01/25/2020
Q-FISCAL FY2020 Q1   07/28/2019 10/26/2019
Q-FISCAL FY2018 Q3   01/26/2018 04/26/2018

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 7: sample data; you already have it in a table, so code you need begins at line #8
- line #9: replace `quarter_name`'s ...
- line #10: ... 4 characters that follow the first space (which is e.g. `FY20`) ...
- lines #12 - 20: ... with

  - line #12: the first 2 characters that follow the first space (which is `FY`) concatenated with ...
  - lines #14 - 20: ... year value expanded to 4 characters (e.g. 20 to 2020 or 18 to 2018)

    - line #16: year part of the `FY20` substring (so it is e.g. `20` or `18`)
    - line #17: apply `rrrr` format mask to it (using `to_date` function) so that it becomes e.g. `2020`; if it were `yyyy` format mask, you'd get `0020`. Result of this is e.g. `01/01/2020 00:00:00` - full date with time
    - line #19: apply the same `rrrr` format mask to that date value (using `to_char` function) in order to extract only year from e.g. `01/01/2020 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is turn quarter names like 'Q-FISCAL   FY20 Q3' into years, then this is a mere string operation:

```
select 'FY20' || substr(quarter_name, 14, 2) from ...
```

If you have years before 2000 in the table, then use a `CASE` expression, e.g.:

```
select
  case when to_number(substr(quarter_name, 14, 2)) > 30
    then 'FY19' || substr(quarter_name, 14, 2)
    else 'FY20' || substr(quarter_name, 14, 2)
  end as year,
  start_period,
  end_period
from mytable;
```